# Extract Most Significant Nibble using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to extract the Most Significant Nibble out of a byte using Swift 2.

Example:

```
0x50 -> 5, 0x6A -> 6, etc.
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: How is your byte represented ? Int ? String ?
If it's an Int or a numerical value, simply divide it by 16 or shift it of 4 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let value = 0x6A
let nibble = value >> 4
```